# Database already in sync with current entity metadata - Symfony

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've searched the internet for a whole day but still no solution. I notice a lot of people have experienced this issue but there's no specific answer so here's my scenario:

I'm using FOSUserBundle on Symfony 3 and i created my "User Entity" in `AppBundle\Entity\User`. I made some corrections to some annotations in "User.php" file and tried to update doctrine using this command: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

I got the message  "**Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.**". I also tried `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete` and `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and got the same message above.

I cleared my cache using several commands: `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`, `bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`, `bin/console cache:clear` and tried updating again but still got the same message.

My entity User.php:

```
<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table (name = "fos_user")
 */

Class User extends BaseUser{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
 */ 
protected $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
 */ 
protected $lastName;
```

Also i have added the entity in AppKernel.php (and fosuserbundle too) like this

```
new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

Please What could be causing doctrine not to update the DB?.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see your entity in `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` ? Make sure that you check correct database - maybe one configured in app is already updated. Do you have fos user configured in `config.yml`?

Comment: Fos User is configured in config.yml... `fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
`
Also i see my entity after running the command above. This is what i get: `[OK]  AppBundle\Entity\User
 [OK]  FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk  So in my `User.php` i changed the table name from **fos_user** to  **tbl_user**  ,  And it worked. Strange right?

Comment: it looks like `fos_user` was already in sync with all entity changes - i don't see other explanation.